# Join by range and group in dplyr pipe

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I have a several large data frames that I need to append data to. The data structure is simulated below:

**Orders**

```
set.seed(2)
N=1e2

tbl.orders <- tibble(
  ID=1:N,
  nb_products_ordered = sample(1:15, N, replace = TRUE),
  type = sample(c("keyboard", "mouse", "other"), N, replace = TRUE),
  grade= sample(LETTERS[1:5], N, replace=TRUE)
)

# A tibble: 100 x 4
    ID  nb_products_ordered     type       grade
  <int>               <int>     <chr>      <chr>
1     1                   5     other       A    
2     2                  15     keyboard    A    
3     3                   6     other       C    
4     4                   6     keyboard    E    
5     5                   8     other       C
```

**Bulk pricing**. Prices are variable depending on the number of products ordered.
The table shows the minimum number of products at which bulk pricing applies.
Other products are not counted and their price is to be considered "NA".

```
tbl.prices <- tibble::tribble(
  ~min_products_ordered, ~per_unit_cost, ~type,
  1L, 39.7,    "mouse",
  2L, 23.1,    "mouse",
  3L, 18.6,    "mouse",
  4L,   15,    "mouse",
  5L, 14.3,    "mouse",
  6L,   11,    "mouse",
  9L, 10.9,    "mouse",
  1L,   11, "keyboard",
  9L, 10.9, "keyboard"
)
```

**My convoluted solution**, which seems overly complex and is rather slow when running on my large data frames (500K+ rows each). Is there a simpler, faster way? I ultimately want it in a pipe because I have transformations before and after.

```
tbl.orders%>%
group_by(type)%>%
      group_split()%>%
      lapply(., function(x)
      {
        #if included in price list
        if (x$type[1] %in% levels(factor(tbl.prices$type))) {
          df.priceparameters <- tbl.prices %>%
            filter(type == x$type[1])

          x %>% mutate(
            per_unit_cost =
              as.numeric(
                as.character(
              
              cut(
                x[["nb_products_ordered"]],
                breaks = c(df.priceparameters$min_products_ordered, Inf),
                #returns per unit cost
                labels = df.priceparameters$per_unit_cost,
                right = FALSE
              )))
          )
        } else{
          x %>% mutate(per_unit_cost = NA)
        }
      })%>%
      do.call("rbind",.)%>%
  arrange(ID)
```

**Result**

```
# A tibble: 100 x 5
     ID  nb_products_ordered  type     grade  per_unit_cost
  <int>                <int>  <chr>    <chr>          <dbl>
1     1                   5   other    A                NA  
2     2                  15   keyboard A               10.9
3     3                   6   other    C                NA  
4     4                   6   keyboard E                11  
5     5                   8   other    C                NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt which also seems bit convoluted :

We write a function to select the correct value of prices for each `ID`.

```
library(dplyr)

select_row <- function(type, nb_products_ordered, min_products_ordered){
  if(any(type == 'other')) return(TRUE) 
  else{
    tmp <- first(nb_products_ordered) - min_products_ordered 
    inds <- tmp >= 0
    if(any(inds)) return(tmp == min(tmp[inds], na.rm = TRUE))
    else TRUE
  }
}
```

Join the dataframe by `type` and select the row for each `ID`.

```
tbl.orders %>%
  left_join(tbl.prices, by = 'type') %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(select_row(type, nb_products_ordered, min_products_ordered))
```

Comment: Smart way of finding the right price category. Thanks !

Comment: I think you code requires a tweak because if someone orders 1 item, they wouldn't be detected `tmp >= 0`

Comment: You are right. I missed that. I have updated the answer accordingly.